# Are algebroids "just matrices"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, enriched-category-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Vect{Vect}\DeclareMathOperator\Mat{Mat}$This question was originally asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723838/are-algebroids-just-matrices) but may be better here.

[Algebroids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebroid) are particularly interesting structures: they are basically categories enriched over $\Vect_K$ for some field $K$. This means the hom-sets are all vector spaces, and composition is "bilinear" in a certain sense. (Let's just focus on when $K$ is a field for now rather than an arbitrary ring.)

Most examples I can think of are basically equivalent to some subset of matrices with the usual addition and multiplication rules, as long as we are willing to be creative and allow "infinite matrices" of various cardinalities to exist. In general, for any $n$ and $m$, the set of $n \times m$ matrices forms an algebroid, as long as we also allow the $n \times n$ and $m \times m$ identity matrices to exist. The union of any such sets also forms an algebroid, as long as matrix compositions exist when expected (meaning if we have $5 \times 4$ and $4 \times 3$ matrices, we must also have $5 \times 3$ matrices, as well as the relevant identity matrices). This is also true if $n$ and $m$ are arbitrary infinite cardinals, with the caveat that only finitely many elements of each column of the matrix can be nonzero.

So, we can ask if this is basically "what algebroids are." It is a little bit difficult to even figure out how to formalize the question, but we can think about it in the following sense:

Let's say that the category $\Mat^+_K$ is basically an extension of the usual $\Mat_K$, but with the objects as all possible *cardinals* rather than only natural numbers. For objects $\kappa$, $\lambda$, the morphisms $\kappa \to \lambda$ are (possibly infinite) matrices of size $\kappa \times \lambda$ (treating these cardinals as initial ordinals), with finitely many nonzero coefficients in each column, taking values in $K$.

As a sort of first pass, we would then like to ask the following "pre-question":

**Naive Pre-Question**: is every possible $K$-algebroid equivalent to a subcategory of $\Mat_K^+$?

The main problem with this is that we can take a disjoint union of two $\Mat_K^+$'s. This will be a $K$-algebroid, but as we haven't drawn explicit isomorphism arrows between the two copies of each object, I don't think the two categories will be equivalent.

But, we can salvage the spirit of the question by noting that $\Mat_K^+$ is a skeleton category of $\Vect_K$, which has infinitely many copies of the things in $\Mat_K^+$ with all possible linear transformations (and thus isomorphisms, when they exist) between them. So, we can thus ask our real question:

**Real Question**: is every possible $K$-algebroid equivalent to a subcategory of $\Vect_K$?

---

EDIT: It has been pointed out in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449656/are-algebroids-just-matrices#comment1161885_449656) that this can fail due to size issues, e.g. you can have an algebroid so large that it isn't concretizable. I guess that technically answers the way I formulated the "real question" above, as I hadn't thought of that snag, but still looking to get clarity on the algebraic relationship of these things beyond that sort of thing, so would be happy to see it addressed for small algebroids.

Comment: This question (in the second form) is the $K$-enriched analogue of the question: is every category equivalent to some subcategory of $Set$? Such categories are called concretizable, and counterexamples are known.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie that is very interesting. How are these things the same? What is the simplest non-concretizable algebroid one can build?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we take the large but locally small category $\mathcal{C}$ described by Isbell in Example 2.4 of

- *Two set-theoretical theorems in categories*, Fundamenta Mathematicae **53** Issue 1 (1964) pp 43-49, ([EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/213746)),

namely, with class of objects $(\{1,2\}\times\mathrm{ORD}) \sqcup \{X,Y\}$, and generated by maps $f_{\alpha,X}\colon (1,\alpha) \to X$, $f_{\alpha,Y}\colon (1,\alpha) \to Y$, $g_{X,\alpha}\colon X\to (2,\alpha)$, $g_{Y,\alpha}\colon Y\to (2,\alpha)$, for each ordinal $\alpha \in \mathrm{ORD}$, with the relation that $\forall \alpha$ forces $g_{X,\alpha}\circ f_{\alpha,X} = g_{Y,\alpha}\circ f_{\alpha,Y}$, and such that we also keep the two composites $g_{X,\beta}\circ f_{\alpha,X}$ and $g_{Y,\beta}\circ f_{\alpha,Y}$ distinct for $\alpha\neq \beta$.

The free $K$-algebroid $K[\mathcal{C}]$ on this category, namely take the free vector space on the hom-sets over any field $K$, and extend composition bilinearly, cannot admit a faithful functor to $K\text{-}\mathrm{Vect}$, since otherwise there would be a faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \to K[\mathcal{C}] \to K\text{-}\mathrm{Vect} \to \mathrm{Set}$, which Isbell proved cannot happen.

EDIT: For small algebroids, there is no issue: for every small algebroid $\mathcal{A}$ we can send an object $a$ to the vector space that is the *direct sum* over all $\mathcal{A}(x,a)$ as $x$ varies over all objects. This gives a faithful functor to vector spaces.

It is only for large algebroids where the issues come in. There are large algebroids where the construction in the previous paragraph still works and gives a functor to the category of vector spaces. For example, a large algebroid $\mathcal{A}$ such that for each object $a$, only a set's worth of hom-spaces $\mathcal{A}(x,a)$ are nontrivial vector spaces. For example the free $K$-algebroid on the opposite of $\mathrm{ORD}$ (arrows point to smaller ordinals), so that hom-spaces are either $K$ or $0$, and only set-many are $K$.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRoberts. That is a very interesting example. I am not sure if I get it all correctly, but I guess the idea is if we didn't have that relation making the two compositions equal, we would then have the faithful functor? I guess the basic idea is, given some algebroid which *is* equivalent to a subcategory of $K-Vect$, we can take a disjoint union of two copies of the same algebroid, and then take a quotient such that we partially identify morphisms together such that we don't get the faithful functor. Is that the idea?

Comment: @Mike that's now how Isbell thought of it. He was only interested in finding a condition that all concetisable categories satisfied, and then an example that failed this condition. But given that Freyd's subsequent work shows that every locally small category is the "homotopy category" of a concrete category (by identifying parallel arrows under a suitable equivalence relation), you are at least in the ballpark of the idea.

Comment: There might well be $K$-algebroids that aren't embeddable in $K\text{-}\mathrm{Vect}$ for algebraic reasons, not just because of facts about non-concrete categories, but I don't know enough to make a guess on that.

Comment: I'm happy to guess that any small algebroid embeds in a category of vector spaces, probably by the enriched Yoneda lemma. So then you need to take a large algebroid. It's not just a matter of taking two copies of the same algebroid, but something to do with size issues.

Comment: OK, I may have misunderstood. Is the problem here *entirely* due to size issues? I guess I hadn't thought of that little snag when I formulated the question. Is that the only possible way that things can go wrong here? I guess I'd be happy enough if every "small algebroid" we equivalent to a subcategory of Vect, and would deem algebroids to be "just matrices" except for this quirk with size issues I don't quite get. But I'm curious if there's some other reason, aside from size issues, why some arbitrary K-algebroid wouldn't embed into K-Vect.

Comment: Any small (and locally small) category $\mathcal{A}$ is concrete via the functor sending an object $a$ to the set of all arrows with source $a$ or in other words, the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{x\in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{A})} \mathcal{A}(x,a)$. This can even work for suitable large categories, as should be clear. For the small algebroid case, we can send an object $a$ to the vector space that is the _direct sum_ over all $\mathcal{A}(x,a)$ as $x$ varies over all objects. This gives a functor to vector spaces, and it may very well be faithful (I can't check right now).

Comment: Now one might have a large algebroid $\mathcal{A}$ such that for each object $a$, only a set's worth of hom-spaces $\mathcal{A}(x,a)$ are nontrivial vector spaces. For example the free algebroid on the opposite of $\mathrm{ORD}$ (arrows point to smaller ordinals), so that hom-spaces are either $K$ or $0$, and only set-many are $K$. For these, the functor in the previous comment can still be constructed.

Comment: Your proposed functor is just the composite of the usual concretization functor (on the underlying ordinary category of $\mathcal A$) with the free vector space functor, which is faithful, so it does give a faithful functor from any small algebroid to vector spaces.

Comment: @KevinArlin Thanks, I assumed it would be, I was not able to stop and think about it at the time.

Comment: FWIW I did accept this answer, but it would be good if there were a note just indicating that the answer is "yes" for small algebroids and "no" for large ones due to these size issues.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! I've expanded the answer, incorporating information from my comments, making explicit the size effects.